# Mac is flashing screen when pressing keys

Tags: macos

If I press keys that don't do anything on the focused app then the whole screen flashes white, as if the option to flash the screen on alerts (in accessibility preferences) was on, but it is not.

For example typing this question the screen does not flash, because pressing the keys is doing something, but If I'm on an app where there is no text field that can be focused pressing keys will make the screen flash white.

Answer (score 6):

I think there's an option in System Preferences.
Go to`System Preferences > Accessibility > Audio` and uncheck the box that says `Flash the screen when an alert occurs`.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in High Sierra (10.13.6) and a system restart solved it.